# list not callable when trying to add to list from running program

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a function, in which the user types in something and that something they typed is added to a list.

I tried putting [] around my code as one person said. But it didn't work.

```py
def admin():
    running = False
    print('welcome to admin mode')
    adminOptions = ['Option 1', 'Option 2']
    print(adminOptions)
    selectOption = input('Please type in an option:')
    if selectOption == 'Option 1':
            adminOptions(1)

def adminOptions(opt):
    pcList1 = ['Home Basic PC - $900-$1199', 'Office Computer - $1200-$1499','Gaming PC - $1500-$2199','Studio PC - $2200+']
    if opt == 1:
         newItem = input('Please type in the new item, Admin. ')
         pcList1.append[newItem]
         print('Here is the new list')
         print(pcList1)  

#maincode
admin()
```

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You have 2 names `adminOptions` in your code: the function `def adminOptions(opt):` and the list `adminOptions = ['Option 1', 'Option 2']`. You seem to be in disagreement with Python about which you are referring to when you use `adminOptions(1)`.  You should consider renaming the list so it doesn't shadow the function name.

Comment: Please search up documentation of the append() function. If you change `pcList1.append[newItem]` to `pcList1.append(newItem)`, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use the name `adminOptions` two times, once for a list (line 4 and 5), and then for the function definition on line 10.

When you try to call the function `adminOptions()` inside `admin()`, python sees that there is already a local variable with that name (a list), and tries to call it, while a list is not callable, you get the TypeError you saw.

modify the name of the local variable inside `admin()` to something else:

```py
def admin():
    running = False
    print('welcome to admin mode')
    adminOptionsList = ['Option 1', 'Option 2']
    print(adminOptionsList)
    selectOption = input('Please type in an option:')
    if selectOption == 'Option 1':
        adminOptions(1)

def adminOptions(opt):
    pcList1 = ['Home Basic PC - $900-$1199', 'Office Computer - $1200-$1499','Gaming PC - $1500-$2199','Studio PC - $2200+']
    if opt == 1:
        newItem = input('Please type in the new item, Admin. ')
        pcList1.append(newItem)
        print('Here is the new list')
        print(pcList1)  

#maincode
admin()
```

hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the need to change adminOption, you're also encountering an error when you try to append to pcList1:

```
def admin():
    running = False
    print('welcome to admin mode')
    adminOptionsList = ['Option 1', 'Option 2']
    print(adminOptionsList)
    selectOption = input('Please type in an option:')
    if selectOption == 'Option 1':
        AdminOptions(1)

def AdminOptions(opt):
    pcList1 = ['Home Basic PC - $900-$1199', 'Office Computer - $1200-$1499','Gaming PC - $1500-$2199','Studio PC - $2200+']
    if opt == 1:
        newItem = input('Please type in the new item, Admin. ')
        pcList1.append(newItem)   #Parentheses are needed, not brackets
        print('Here is the new list')
        print(pcList1)  

#maincode
admin()
```

append() is a method, so you'll need parentheses.